# Performance tweak for expanding().mean() over groups

Tags: python, pandas, performance

Having the following DF of user events:

```
    id                timestamp
0    1  2021-11-23 11:01:00.000
1    1  2021-11-23 11:02:00.000
2    1  2021-11-23 11:10:00.000
3    1  2021-11-23 11:11:00.000
4    1  2021-11-23 11:22:00.000
5    1  2021-11-23 11:40:00.000
6    1  2021-11-23 11:41:00.000
7    1  2021-11-23 11:42:00.000
8    1  2021-11-23 11:43:00.000
9    1  2021-11-23 11:44:00.000
10   2  2021-11-23 11:01:00.000
11   2  2021-11-23 11:02:00.000
12   2  2021-11-23 11:10:00.000
13   2  2021-11-23 11:11:00.000
14   2  2021-11-23 11:22:00.000
15   2  2021-11-23 11:40:00.000
16   2  2021-11-23 11:41:00.000
17   2  2021-11-23 11:42:00.000
18   2  2021-11-23 11:43:00.000
19   2  2021-11-23 11:44:00.000
```

I calculate the average session time per row as follows:

1. Each session is a sequence of events less than 5 minutes apart.
2. I calculate the number of seconds between the first event in the session and the current event.
3. I then calculate expanding().mean() for each user.

Here is my code:

```
def average_session_time(**kwargs):
    df = kwargs['df'].copy()
    df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df.timestamp)
    df['session_grp'] = df.groupby('id').apply(
        lambda x: (x.groupby([pd.Grouper(key="timestamp", freq='5min', origin='start')])).ngroup()).reset_index(
        drop=True).values.reshape(-1)

    # Getting relevant 5min groups
    ng = df.groupby(['id', 'session_grp'])
    df['fts'] = ng['timestamp'].transform('first')
    df['delta'] = df['timestamp'].sub(df['fts']).dt.total_seconds()

    return df.groupby('id')['delta'].expanding().mean().reset_index(drop=True)
```

And the output is:

```
0      0.000000
1     30.000000
2     20.000000
3     15.000000
4     12.000000
5     10.000000
6      8.571429
7     15.000000
8     26.666667
9     42.000000
10     0.000000
11    30.000000
12    20.000000
13    15.000000
14    12.000000
15    10.000000
16     8.571429
17    15.000000
18    26.666667
19    42.000000
Name: delta, dtype: float64
```

The code works fine, but when it's run on a large data set, the performance suffers and it takes a long time to calculate. I tried tweaking the code, but couldn't gain more performance. How can I write this function differently to improve performance?

[Here is a Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/10SJMaOrI8U7Y4rhjDF_hw5AuaNL00ANj?usp=sharing) with the running code.

Comment: Can you give an idea of the magnitude of size of the DataFrame you're working with and what sort of compute time would be acceptable?

Comment: @mark-rotteveel I got no threshold for performance time but I do want to do it as quick as possible. DF size is around 70,000 rows.

Comment: Did you mean to address @bicarlsen?

Comment: @ShlomiSchwartz I'm running your code with 1E6 rows and 1E4 ids and it's only taking ( 1 +/- 0.4 ) s.

Comment: @bicarlsen mmm ... does your data contains multiple rows per id?

Comment: @bicarlsen I've updated the colab to contain a sample of the data, you can now clearly see the issue. P.S I meant 70K uids not 70K rows. the actual row count of the sample is 3138280

Comment: Are the Ids always packed? I mean that two row sharing the same Id are always in the same contiguous block of row sharing the same Id?

Answer (score 6):

One very fast solution is to use **Numpy** and **Numba** together to group the consecutive lines the way you do.

First of all, the columns needs to be converted to native Numpy types since **CPython objects are very slow to compute** (and also take more memory). You can do that with:

```py
ids = df['Id'].values.astype('S32')
timestamps = df['timestamp'].values.astype('datetime64[ns]')
```

This assume that the IDs are composed of up to 32 ASCII characters. If IDs can contain unicode characters, you can use `'U32'` instead (a bit slower). You can also use `np.unicode_` to let Numpy find the bound for you. However, this is significantly slower (since Numpy need to parse all the strings twice).

Once converted to `datetime64[ns]`, timestamps can be converted to 64-bit integers for a very fast computation by Numba.

Then, the idea is to transform string IDs to basic integers since **working with strings is pretty slow**. You can do that by searching for adjacent strings that are different so to locate blocks having the same ID:

```py
ids_int = np.insert(np.cumsum(ids[1:] != ids[:-1], dtype=np.int64), 0, 0)
```

Note that there are no set of rows sharing the same ID with another row having a different ID in between in the provided dataset. If this assumption is not always true, you can sort the input strings (`ids`) using an `np.argsort(ids, kind='stable')`, apply this solution and then reorder the result based on the output of `np.argsort`. Note that sorting the strings is a bit slow but still much faster than the computation time of the solution provided in the question (about 100-200 ms on my machine).

Finally, you can compute the result with Numba using basic loops.

---

### Complete solution

Here is the resulting code:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import numba as nb

@nb.njit('float64[:](int64[::1], int64[::1])')
def compute_result(ids, timestamps):
    n = len(ids)
    result = np.empty(n, dtype=np.float64)
    if n == 0:
        return result
    id_group_first_timestamp = timestamps[0]
    session_group_first_timestamp = timestamps[0]
    id_group_count = 1
    id_group_delta_sum = 0.0
    last_session_group = 0
    result[0] = 0
    delay = np.int64(300e9) # 5 min (in ns)
    for i in range(1, n):
        # If there is a new group of IDs
        if ids[i-1] != ids[i]:
            id_group_first_timestamp = timestamps[i]
            id_group_delta_sum = 0.0
            id_group_count = 1
            last_session_group = 0
            session_group_first_timestamp = timestamps[i]
        else:
            id_group_count += 1
        session_group = (timestamps[i] - id_group_first_timestamp) // delay
        # If there is a new session group
        if session_group != last_session_group:
            session_group_first_timestamp = timestamps[i]
        delta = (timestamps[i] - session_group_first_timestamp) * 1e-9
        id_group_delta_sum += delta
        result[i] = id_group_delta_sum / id_group_count
        last_session_group = session_group
    return result

def fast_average_session_time(df):
    ids = df['Id'].values.astype('S32')
    timestamps = df['timestamp'].values.astype('datetime64[ns]').astype(np.int64)
    ids_int = np.insert(np.cumsum(ids[1:] != ids[:-1], dtype=np.int64), 0, 0)
    return compute_result(ids_int, timestamps)
```

Note that the output is a Numpy array and not a dataframe but you can easily build a dataframe from a Numpy array with `pd.DataFrame(result)`.

---

### Benchmark

Here is the resulting performance on my machine:

```
Initial solution:            12_537 ms   (   x1.0)
Scott Boston's solution:      7_431 ms   (   x1.7)
This solution:                   64 ms   ( x195.9)

Time taken by 
compute_result only:              2.5 ms
```

Thus, this solution is nearly **200 times** faster than the initial one.

Note that about *85% of the time is spent in unicode/datetime string parsing* that can hardly be optimized. Indeed, this processing is slow because dealing with short unicode strings is inherently expensive on modern processors and also because CPython objects introduce a significant overhead (eg. reference counting). Moreover, this processing cannot be parallelized efficiently because of the CPython GIL and slow inter-process communication. Thus, **this code is certainly almost optimal** (as long as you use CPython).

Answer (score 2):

I think I was able to cut your time in half by using format in pd.to_datetime and also using `as_index`  parameter in groupby instead of calling rest_index:

```
def average_session_time(**kwargs):
    df = kwargs['df'].copy()
    df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df.timestamp, format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
    grp_id = df.groupby('Id', as_index=False)
    df['session_grp'] = grp_id.apply(
        lambda x: (x.groupby([pd.Grouper(key="timestamp", freq='5min', origin='start')])).ngroup()).values.reshape(-1)

    # Getting relevant 5min groups
    ng = df.groupby(['Id', 'session_grp'])
    df['fts'] = ng['timestamp'].transform('first')
    df['delta'] = df['timestamp'].sub(df['fts']).dt.total_seconds()

    return grp_id['delta'].expanding().mean().reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
```

Original Timing:

> 40.228641986846924

New Timing:

> 16.08320665359497